# write table cell real-time python

Tags: python, real-time, pymongo

I would like to loop trough a database, find the appropriate values and insert them in the appropriate cell in a separate file. It maybe a csv, or any other human-readable format.
In pseudo-code:

```
for item in huge_db:
   for list_of_objects_to_match:
      if itemmatch():
         if there_arent_three_matches_yet_in_list():
            matches++
            result=performoperationonitem()
            write_in_file(result, row=object_to_match_id, col=matches)
         if matches is 3:
            remove_this_object_from_object_to_match_list()
```

can you think of any way other than going every time through all the outputfile line by line?
I don't even know what to search for...
even better, there are better ways to find three matching objects in a db and have the results in real-time? (the operation will take a while, but I'd like to see the results popping out RT)

Comment: I can think about creating a set of folder/files instead of a table, but seems an overkill...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `itemmatch()` is a reasonably simple function, this will do what I think you want better than your pseudocode:

```
for match_obj in list_of_objects_to_match:
  db_objects = query_db_for_matches(match_obj)
  if len(db_objects) >= 3:
      result=performoperationonitem()
      write_in_file(result, row=match_obj.id, col=matches)
  else:
      write_blank_line(row=match_obj.id)  # if you want
```

Then the trick becomes writing the `query_db_for_matches()` function.  Without detail, I'll assume you're looking for objects that match in one particular field, call it `type`.  In pymongo such a query would look like:

```
def query_db_for_matches(match_obj):
    return pymongo_collection.find({"type":match_obj.type})
```

To get this to run efficiently, make sure your database has an index on the field(s) you're querying on by first calling:

```
pymongo_collection.ensure_index({"type":1})
```

The first time you call `ensure_index` it could take a long time for a huge collection.  But each time after that it will be fast -- fast enough that you could even put it into `query_db_for_matches` before your `find` and it would be fine.

Comment: Thanks, sadly I'm matching a subset of the value in the db, and the matching function is quite a complicate thing. The question was more on "how to implement "write_in_file(result, row=object_to_match_id, col=matches)" indipendently from the loop running and having the output real-time.

Comment: Sorry - I guess I don't understand what you're asking then.  Not sure what you mean by "real-time" output of a CSV file, especially if you're modifying cells in a non-sequential order.

Comment: I'm sorry! thanks again, and please allow me to restate the question: I want to generate a table (python) and read it in the same time with an html parser (java). The operation to generate table entries are very long and complex, therefore I'd like to process and visualize the results without erasing and rewriting a full file.
I think of using a "seek" and change only the row/cell in a textfile, or perhaps I'll have to use another db...

Comment: It sounds like the thing you're struggling with has basically nothing to do with mongodb.  I think you're looking for a way to send messages between your python process and your java process.  Writing to the middle of a spreadsheet file is definitely not a good answer.  IIWY I'd open a new SO question asking "how do I send real-time message from a python process to a java process?"